# Duvida no relacionamento de banco de dados de uma aplicação usando spring boot

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring-boot, modelo-relacional

Estou desenvolvedo uma aplicação que tem por objetivo cadastrar um fornecedor, no qual esse fornecedor é generico (pode ser uma lanchonete, loja material de construção, uma farmacia... etc) no qual ele vai fornecer produtos na plataforma web. Porem, para o cliente final ter facilidade na busca do produto a que deseja, eu atribui categoria ao fornecedor, para especificar que tipo de categoria o fornecedor se enquadra, dai minha duvida é: como faço para vincular subcategorias de acordo com o tipo de fornecedor. Ex: Se o admin cadastrou o fornecedor farmacia, o usuario responsavel pela farmacia ao cadastrar seus produtos na plataforma terá que escolher somente as subcategorias vinculadas a farmacia(higiene/suplementos/remedios/outros...etc).

Tela de cadastro dos produtos de cada fornecedor. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, se um fornecedor farmacia ta logado, o cadastro de produtos, em subcategorias é pra mostrar as sub correpondente a farmacia, se for um restaurante logado, as sub exibidas serão correspondentes a restaurantes.

Model Usuario:

```
package com.bigboss.comprafacil.models;
@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails, Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotBlank(message = "Nome é uma informação obrigatória.")
@Size(min = 2, max = 30)
private String nome;
private String nomeFantasia;
@NotBlank(message = "Rua é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String rua;
@NotBlank(message = "Bairro é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String bairro;
private String complemento;
@NotBlank(message = "Estado é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String estado;
@NotBlank(message = "Cidade é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String cidade;
@NotBlank(message = "É uma informação obrigatória.")
private String cnpjCpf;
@NotBlank(message = "Telefone é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String telefone;
public String categoria;
@NotBlank(message = "E-mail é uma informação obrigatória.")
@Email(message = "Não é um e-mail válido")
private String email;
@NotBlank(message = "Senha é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String senha;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( 
        name = "usuarios_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "usuario_id", referencedColumnName = "email"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "nomeRole")) 
private List<Role> roles;
public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
    return produtos;
}

public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
    this.produtos = produtos;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public Usuario() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "usuarios_produtos", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "produto_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Produto> produtos;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getNomeFantasia() {
    return nomeFantasia;
}

public void setNomeFantasia(String nomeFantasia) {
    this.nomeFantasia = nomeFantasia;
}

public String getRua() {
    return rua;
}

public void setRua(String rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getComplemento() {
    return complemento;
}

public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
    this.complemento = complemento;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public String getCnpjCpf() {
    return cnpjCpf;
}

public void setCnpjCpf(String cnpjCpf) {
    this.cnpjCpf = cnpjCpf;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>) this.roles;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.senha;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.email;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

Modelo produtos:

```
package com.bigboss.comprafacil.models;

@Entity
public class Produto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
@NotBlank(message = "Nome é uma informação obrigatória.")
public String nome;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
@NotBlank(message = "Descrição é uma informação obrigatória.")
public String descricao;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
@NotBlank(message = "Codigo do produto é uma informação obrigatória.")
public int codigoProduto;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
@NotBlank(message = "Categoria é uma informação obrigatória.")
public String categoria;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
@NotBlank(message = "Unidade de medida é uma informação obrigatória.")
public String unidadeMed;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;
@NotBlank(message = "Preço é uma informação obrigatória.")
public String preco;

public String getPreco() {
    return preco;
}

public void setPreco(String preco) {
    this.preco = preco;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "produtos", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Usuario> usuarios;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
    return usuarios;
}

public void setUsuarios(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
    this.usuarios = usuarios;
}

public Produto() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public int getCodigoProduto() {
    return codigoProduto;
}

public void setCodigoProduto(int codigoProduto) {
    this.codigoProduto = codigoProduto;
}

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getUnidadeMed() {
    return unidadeMed;
}

public void setUnidadeMed(String unidadeMed) {
    this.unidadeMed = unidadeMed;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

}
```

Form fornecedor:

Fornecedores
            Cadastro de fornecedores

```
<section class="forms">
    <form th:object="${usuario}" th:action="@{/fornecedor/save}"
        method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--Input responsável em guardar o id-->

        <div class="container-fluid">
        <th:block th:include="/mensagemValidacao :: mensagem"></th:block>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"
                    th:value="*{id}">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome do empreendimento:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nome" th:field="*{nome}" id="inputNome"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome fantasia:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nomeFantasia" th:field="*{nomeFantasia}"
                            class="form-control" id="inputNomeFantasia">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rua:</label> <input type="text" name="rua"
                            th:field="*{rua}" id="inputRua" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bairro:</label> <input type="text" name="bairro"
                            th:field="*{bairro}" id="inputBairro" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Complemento:</label> <input type="text" name="complemento"
                            th:field="*{complemento}" id="inputComplemento"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cidade:</label> <input type="text" name="cidade"
                            th:field="*{cidade}" id="inputCidade" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Estado:</label> <select name="estado" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{estado}" id="inputEstado">
                            <option th:value="AC">Acre</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                            <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                            <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                            <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                            <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                            <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                            <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                            <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                            <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                            <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                            <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                            <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                            <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                            <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                            <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                            <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                            <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                            <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                            <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                            <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                            <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                            <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>CPF/CNPJ:</label> <input type="text" placeholder=""
                            th:field="*{cnpjCpf}" id="inputcnpjCpf" name="cnpjCpf"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Telefone:</label> <input type="text" placeholder=""
                            th:field="*{telefone}" id="inputTelefone" name="telefone"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Categoria:</label> <select name="categoria"
                            class="form-control" th:field="*{categoria}" id="inputCategoria">
                            <option value="Farmarcias">Farmacias</option>
                            <option value="Lanchonetes">Lanchonetes</option>
                            <option value="Material de construçao">Material de
                                Construçao</option>
                            <option value="Restaurantes">Restaurantes</option>
                            <option value="Pizzarias">Pizzarias</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Adicionar foto do perfil:</label> <input type="file"
                            name="" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email"
                            th:field="*{email}" id="inputEmail" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="exemplo@dominio.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password" name="senha"
                            th:field="*{senha}" id="inputSenha" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirmar senha:</label> <input type="password"
                            placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres" name="senha"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
                        onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/listar';">
                        Cancelar</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Form produtos:

Produtos
            Cadastro de produtos

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <th:block th:include="/mensagemValidacao :: mensagem"></th:block>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"
                    th:value="*{id}">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Código do produto:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="codigoProduto" th:field="*{codigoProduto}" id="inputcodigoProduto"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Valor:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="preco" th:field="*{preco}"
                            class="form-control" id="inputPreco">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nome" th:field="*{nome}" id="inputNome"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Descrição:</label> <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" name="descricao"
                            th:field="*{descricao}" id="inputdescricao" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Unidade de medida:</label> <select name="unidadeMed" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{unidadeMed}" id="inputunidadeMed">
                            <option th:value="UND">UND</option>
                            <option value="CM">CM</option>
                            <option value="METRO">METRO</option>
                            <option value="PCT">PCT</option>
                            <option value="KG">KG</option>
                            <option value="LITRO">LITRO</option>
                            <option value="M²">M²</option>
                            <option value="M³">M³</option>
                            <option value="GRAMA">GRAMA</option>
                            <option value="MILIGRAMA">MILIGRAMA</option>
                            <option value="CAIXA">CAIXA</option>
                            <option value="OUTRO">OUTRO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Sub-categorias:</label> <select name="categoria"
                            class="form-control" th:field="*{categoria}" id="inputCategoria">
                            <option value="Farmarcias">Higiene</option>
                            <option value="Lanchonetes">Suplementos</option>
                            <option value="Material de construçao">Remedios</option>
                            <option value="Restaurantes">Outros</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Adicionar foto do produto:</label> <input type="file"
                            name="" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
                        onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/listar';">
                        Cancelar</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Como modelar o banco de acordo com minha necessidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem sua necessidade, segue o 'modelo' :

> FORNECEDORES (1 x 1)
>   CATEGORIAS (1 fornecedor tem 1 categoria)
>   CATEGORIAS  (n x 1)
>   SUBCATEGORIAS (VARIAS SUBCATEGORIAS PARA UMA CATEGORIA)
>   FORNECEDORES_CATEGORIAS (n n) (varias categorias para vários fornecedores)

sendo assim, teríamos as tabelas:

FORNECEDORES

```
idFornecedor (PK)
...
```

CATEGORIA

```
idCategoria(PK)
...
```

SUBCATEGORIAS

```
idSubcategoria (PK)
idCategoria (FK)
...
```

FORNECEDORES_CATEGORIAS

```
-> CHAVE PRIMARIA COMPOSTA
idFornecedor(PK FK)
idCategoria(PK FK)
...
```

> Coloquei a tabela `FORNECEDORES_CATEGORIAS` pensando na possibilidade de um fornecedor poder fornecer produtos de diferentes categorias.

Sendo assim,para um fornecedor, basta fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM FORNECEDORES_CATEGORIAS fc
INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS c ON c.idCategoria = fc.idCategoria
INNER JOIN SUBCATEGORIAS sub ON sub.idCategoria = fc.idCategoria
WHERE fc.idFornecedor = :idFornecedorLogado
```

Isso irá trazer todas as subcategorias que o fornecedor estaria 'inscrito'.

Comment: e como ficaria o relacionamento subtagoria produtos ou fornecedor produtos?

Comment: PRODUTO
idProduto(PK)
idSubcategoria(FK)
...

Isso levando em consideração que os produto se relacionaria com uma subcategorias e nao com os fornecedor, por ex, **sabonete estaria ligado a subcategoria Higiene e a subcategoria Higiene estaria ligado  a categoria Farmacia que teria o fornecedor X**.

Comment: Ah entendi, vou tentar implementar. obgdo

Comment: Sena pode me ajudar na continuação dessa pergunta aqui, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306570/invalid-property-categoria-subcategoria-of-bean-class-erro-ao-salvar-usuario-n