# Invalid property 'categoria.subcategoria' of bean class. Erro ao salvar usuario no banco

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jpa, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao web que tem o seguinte mapeamento:
Um usuario tem uma categoria;
Uma categoria tem varias subcategorias;
uma subcategoria tem varios produtos. 
Conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O que estou tentando implementar é: quando o admin cadastrar um novo fornecedor ele ira informar os dados pessoais do fornecedor e a categoria do seu empreendimento e as subcategorias de seus produtos. Pois quando o fornecedor fizer o login na plataforma, ja trazer do banco o usuario logado e as subcategorias correspondente ao usuario, para dai ele cadastrar seus produtos, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu model usuario esta:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotBlank(message = "Nome é uma informação obrigatória.")
@Size(min = 2, max = 30)
private String nome;
private String nomeFantasia;
@NotBlank(message = "Rua é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String rua;
@NotBlank(message = "Bairro é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String bairro;
private String complemento;
@NotBlank(message = "Estado é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String estado;
@NotBlank(message = "Cidade é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String cidade;
@NotBlank(message = "É uma informação obrigatória.")
private String cnpjCpf;
private String telefone;
public String categoria;
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

@NotBlank(message = "E-mail é uma informação obrigatória.")
@Email(message = "Não é um e-mail válido")
private String email;
@NotBlank(message = "Senha é uma informação obrigatória.")
private String senha;

private String foto;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Usuario usuario;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "usuarios_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", referencedColumnName = "email"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "nomeRole"))
private List<Role> roles;

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

GETTERS E SETTERS...
```

Model Categoria

```
@Entity
public class Categoria {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")
private Usuario usuario;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "subcategoria_id")
private List<Subcategoria> subcategorias;

GETTERS E SETTERS...
```

Model subcategoria:

```
@Entity
public class Subcategoria {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotBlank(message = "")
private String nome;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subcategoria")
public List<Produto> produtos;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id")
public Categoria categoria;

GETTERS E SETTERS...
```

Model produtos:

```
@Entity
public class Produto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="produto_id")
public Subcategoria subcategoria;
GETTERS E SETTERS...
```

Controller usuarios:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fornecedor")
public class UsuarioController {

@Autowired
private UsuarioService service;

@RequestMapping("/cadastrarFornecedor")
public ModelAndView cadastrarFornecedor(Usuario usuario) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("fornecedor/form");
    mv.addObject("usuario", usuario);
    return mv;
}
@PostMapping("/save")
public ModelAndView save(@Valid Usuario usuario, String senhaconf, @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files, String senha, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    System.out.print(usuario);
    if (result.hasErrors() || !senha.equals(senhaconf)) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "[Verifique os campos!");
        System.out.println("--------erro ao salvar: " + usuario.getId());
        return cadastrarFornecedor(usuario);
    }
    String foto = files[0].getOriginalFilename();
    usuario.setFoto(foto);
    usuario.setSenha(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(senha));
    service.save(usuario);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Evento cadastrado com sucesso!");
    return findAll();
}
```

Pagina do form:

```
<section class="forms">
    <form th:object="${usuario}" id="formQuantidade"
        th:action="@{/fornecedor/save}" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--Input responsável em guardar o id-->

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <th:block th:include="/mensagemValidacao :: mensagem"></th:block>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"
                    th:value="*{id}">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome do empreendimento:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nome" th:field="*{nome}" id="inputNome"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome fantasia:</label> <input type="text"
                            name="nomeFantasia" th:field="*{nomeFantasia}"
                            class="form-control" id="inputNomeFantasia">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rua:</label> <input type="text" name="rua"
                            th:field="*{rua}" id="inputRua" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bairro:</label> <input type="text" name="bairro"
                            th:field="*{bairro}" id="inputBairro" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Complemento:</label> <input type="text" name="complemento"
                            th:field="*{complemento}" id="inputComplemento"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cidade:</label> <input type="text" name="cidade"
                            th:field="*{cidade}" id="inputCidade" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Estado:</label> <select name="estado" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{estado}" id="inputEstado">
                            <option th:value="AC">Acre</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                            <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                            <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                            <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                            <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                            <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                            <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                            <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                            <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                            <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                            <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                            <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                            <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                            <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                            <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                            <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                            <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                            <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                            <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                            <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                            <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                            <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>CPF/CNPJ:</label> <input type="text" placeholder=""
                            id="cpfcnpj" th:field="*{cnpjCpf}" name="cnpjCpf"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Telefone:</label> <input type="text" placeholder=""
                            id="telefone" th:field="*{telefone}" name="telefone"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Categoria:</label> <select name="usuario.categoria"
                            class="form-control" th:field="*{usuario.categoria}" id="inputCategoria">
                            <option value="Farmarcias">Farmacias</option>
                            <option value="Lanchonetes">Lanchonetes</option>
                            <option value="Material de construçao">Material de
                                Construçao</option>
                            <option value="Restaurantes">Restaurantes</option>
                            <option value="Pizzarias">Pizzarias</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <label for="quantidade">Subcategorias</label>
                    <div class="inputs">
                        <input type="text" name="campo[]" class="form-control" th:field="*{categoria.subcategoria}"
                            placeholder=""> <br>
                    </div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="adicionarcampo"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn btn-success">Nova subcategoria</a>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email"
                            th:field="*{email}" id="inputEmail" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="exemplo@dominio.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password" name="senha"
                            th:field="*{senha}" id="inputSenha" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirmar senha:</label> <input type="password"
                            placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres" name="senhaconf"
                            class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
                        onclick="window.location.href='/fornecedor/lista';">
                        Cancelar</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Do jeito que está ele da o seguinte erro:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'categoria.subcategoria' of bean class [com.bigboss.comprafacil.models.Usuario]: Bean property 'categoria.subcategoria' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Como se nao tivesse os gets e sets de subcategorias ou usuarios, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olha sua exception apontando para "categoria.subcategoria" (na sua estrutura, esse bidding não existe). Se não mudou depois do Spring 3 em diante, quando você quer mandar uma lista para o backend, o name dos input precisam estar indexados, ex: categoria.subcategorias[0].nome = "categoria 1"; categria.subcategorias[1].nome = "categoria 2"; categria.subcategorias[0].produtos[0].nome = "Nome produto 1"; e assim por diante. Deste modo, o spring vai fazer bidding automaticamente.

Comment: acho q nao da certo, se nao seria preciso um for, para popular o vetor.

Comment: Se os names do seu formulário bater com a estrutura do dos seus objetos no backend ele já vai chegar preenchido no seu método. Você não irá precisar de um for para preencher (a menos que você esteja no fluxo de montar o formulário na tela, ai você irá precisar de um for indexado para poder colocar os indices nas posições corretas).

Comment: Confirme também o mapeamento das suas entidades (no objeto Usuário tem uma associação com Usuário falando que o nome da coluna é id_categoria ??), chegando em casa se for o caso eu desenho como deve ficar o form e posto aqui.

Comment: @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Usuario usuario;  Os names do meu form estao batendo, a duvida é como salvar no banco usando o name correto. TIpo salvar o usuario logado com o produto vinculado a subcategoria que por sua vez esta vinculado a categoria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o que falta é fazer categoria.subcategoriaS (no plural) e não categoria.subcategoria (no singular)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo, na sua Class Categoria você criou dessa seguinte forma:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "subcategoria_id")
private List<Subcategoria> subcategorias;
```

Tudo certo nesse passo, já na sua Class SubCategoria:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subcategoria")
public List<Produto> produtos;
```

Você está fazendo um mappedBy para um atributo que não existe em seu código.

Para solucionar o seu problema do fornecedor vê somente os dados do mesmo indico a você criar uma "sessão" e salvar o usuário que está usando logado nela e assim filtrar tudo que esse usuário pode visualizar tipo:

```
Usuario usuarioBanco = usuarioDao.get(usuario.id);
```

Algo nesse nível afim de filtrar o usuário da sessão.